# Connecting to Compose.io MongoDB deployment using SSL and mongos through Mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl, compose-db

I'm using compose.io for hosting test and production mongodb databases and am attempting to connect through a node app using mongoose.js (which uses the standard nodejs mongodb driver under the hood). My connection options are as follows:

```
var connectionString = 'mongodb://user:password@host1:port1,host2:port2/dbname?ssl=true';

var options = {
  mongos: true,
  server: {
    ssl: true,
    sslValidate: true,
    sslCA: [fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert/certificate.pem')] // cert from compose.io dashboard
  }
}

mongoose.createConnection(connectionString, options);
```

The connection just seems to hang, though. I don't receive an error from the server, nor do I receive an 'open' event.

Comment: The [Compose.io docs for MongoDB with Mongoose](https://help.compose.io/docs/connecting-to-mongodb#section-connecting-with-mongoose-javascript-) help here.

Answer (score 9):

*ANSWER*

I was able to fix the issue by moving all of the options from `server` into `mongos`:

```
var options = {
  mongos: {
    ssl: true,
    sslValidate: true,
    sslCA: [fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert/certificate.pem')] // cert from compose.io dashboard
  }
}
```